# Why python return float values?

Tags: python

Why does my return float values for 12/3 = 4.0 ??

I'm trying to divide those two values for example

```
x = 12
y = 3
```

why i'm getting float values like 4.0 it's must 4 right ?

Need a good explanation from above method.

Hope will receive good answers.

Comment: If you want `int` why don't you do `x//y`?

Comment: Using your example you get an integer as return value (`x=12` `y=3` `x/y=4` and not `4.0`). Please post a complete example that results in a float value from that division